# How do I remove the first element in a list within a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to know if there's any way to remove an index in a list within a list. For example, given `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`, I would like to remove the the first element of each list so that it becomes `[[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]`. I can do a for loop to slowly remove them but I was wondering if there's a more efficient manner to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you have two options.

You can use `pop()`:

```
for item in list:
    item.pop(0)
```

Or recreate a new list :

```
list2 = [item[1:] for item in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with iterating over the list, and then call the pop() function on the inner list. This will remove an element at the specified index.

```
test_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for i in test_list:
    i.pop(0)

print(test_list)
```

output: `[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]`

Answer (score 0):

For small `list`s as in your example, doing something like `list.pop(0)` is OK:

```
nested = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
for inner in nested:
    inner.pop(0)  # Remove first element of each inner list
```

However, as `list`s are basically implemented as arrays (of pointers), removing the first element means that all other elements has to be shifted back by one, resulting in a lot of (pointer) copying if your `list`s are large. Also, using `inner[1:]` rather than `inner.pop(0)` does not solve the problem, as `inner[1:]` creates a new `list` rather than returning a view.

One way out is to make the redundant elements appear as the last element instead of the first, so that you can do `inner.pop()` instead, which removes the last element. No further shifting/copying is then required.

Another solution is to switch out your data structure from a `list` to a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) ("double-ended queue"). This has a `popleft()` method, which is equivalent to `pop(0)` but fast, as `deque`s support fast popping from both ends:

```
import collections
nested = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
nested = [collections.deque(inner) for inner in nested]  # list of deques
for inner in nested:
    inner.popleft()  # Remove first element of each inner list, fast!
```